# How to use else/elseif?

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I struggle with some if-else clause and would to have an advise on how to set the logic.

I have the following code:

```
//if isset a or b
if (isset(a) || isset(b) ) {
        //if isset a
    if (isset(a)) {
            switch(a) {
                case '1' : $num = '1';
                break;
                case '2' : $num = '2';
                break;
                case '3' : $num = '3';
                break;
            }
    //if not isset a check b for $num
        } else if (isset(b)) {
            switch(b){
                case '1' : $num = '1';
                break;
                case '2' : $num = '2';
                break;
                case '3' : $num = '3';
                break;
            }
        }
//if not isset a and b, set default 
} else {
        $num = '1';
    }
```

The problem is that I did not get it when to use else/ else if. So I would like to know if I`m right with that code and my commented lines.

Thanks alot.

Comment: Your `else if (isset(b))` is not necessary, because if `a` is not set, then `b` has to be set because of your first if clause. You could just use `else`

Comment: What if both are set?

Comment: Well, that depends on his needs. If `a` is more important than `b`, he should use `else` instead. If not, he could leave it like this.

Comment: It's not necessary but perhaps logical but it's an overhead, yes. What he means is that you could just do if a else if b else num = 1

Comment: You can remove the outermost if

Comment: this is really verbose.  why are you using switch statements?

Comment: a and b are constants?

Comment: thanks for answering at all. this code is for setting a default language setting. a comes from a Cookie, b is a Session.

Comment: @all, I`m sorry I made a mistake. Thought to shorten the code and was not thinking of only 1 and 2, there are a lot more options than only 2 from the switch. So I updated the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, if your `if-else` structure is too complicated (more than two levels of curly brackets), this is the best time for *divide and conquer* approach: create functions that solve separated problems.

```
function getNum(&$a, &$b, $options) { 
  if(isset($a) && in_array($a,$options)) return $a;
  if(isset($b) && in_array($b,$options)) return $b;
  return 1;
}

$options = array(1,'2','whatever');
$num = getNum($a,$b,$options);
```

With this approach, the problem is just a matter of the function body, so you can solve it separatedly from the rest of the code. And that is the desired easily maintainable structure.

Comment: Hello and thanks. I`m sorry I made a mistake. Thought to shorten the code and was not thinking of only 1 and 2, there are a lot more options than only 2 from the switch. So I updated the code.

Comment: I see - I updated the answer - see the latter part of the code.

Comment: Okay, this is quiet simple but works only if a and b is numeric. in my case a and b contains strings.

Comment: updated again (and removed the less interesting part of the answer)

Answer (score 2):

> Generally, if your if-else structure is too complicated (more than two
>   levels of curly ?brackets), this is the best time for divide and
>   conquer approach: create functions that solve separated problems.

1. While **this is correct**, your structure is acceptable. Most programmers would *wish* that this is changed, but if you are comfortable working this way and you understand it, it will still work.
2. Secondly, your `else if (isset(b))` may or may not be necessary based on whether both can be set. If they can't, you can just replace your `else if (isset(b))` with `else`.

Ok, I am not sure whether you need this, but here is a quick explanation of `if`, `else if`, and `else`.

`if (condition)` is used to test whether the condition is true or false. If it is true, the code between the `{` and `}` is executed. Otherwise, it is not.

`else if` requires the above `if`'s condition to have been false. If your `if`'s condition is false but any following `else if` is true, that `else if` will execute.

Finally, if all the `if` and `else if`'s conditions have returned false, the `else`'s code is executed.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid a lot of the control flow issues using the following method.

```
if(isset(a)) {
    $num = a;
} else if(isset(b)) {
    $num = b;
}

$arr = array('1', '2', '3');
if(!in_array($num, $arr)) {
    $num = '1';
}
```

Comment: hello and thanks.  I`m sorry I made a mistake. Thought to shorten the code and was not thinking of only 1 and 2, there are a lot more options than only 2 from the switch. So I updated the code.

Comment: @bonny Updated to handle any number you want to add later.

Answer (score 0):

```
//default
$num = '1';

if(isset(a)) {
  $num = a;
} else if(isset(b)) {
  $num = b;
}
```

Comment: my only issue with this is we don't know id `$num = a` is valid. If it is this a good solution.